# Caspian Sea oil deposits

Tags: oceanography, models, petroleum

Azerbaijan appears to have vast development in its oil sector.  Images on google earth show oil platforms connected by road ways far out into the Caspian Sea of the coast of Baku.  Why is the majority of the sea un available to view. How vast are these deposits?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "Why is the majority of the sea un available to view". Please can you edit to clarify?

If the question is simply "How big are Azerbaijan's oil reserves", you might just ask that.

Comment: Very "vast". The Baku has been produced for  well over 100 years and is still a major producer. And with political stability and money , modern production technology could produce a lot of the oil that is left in the older deposits.